# Complex log branches

Tags: complex-analysis

As I understand, we get the principal branch of the complex logarithm by the choice of $Arg(z) $ to be in the segment $ (-\pi,\pi)$.

As I understood, it means **excluding the negative part of the real axis**

Can anyone explain the relation between excluding the negative part of the real axis and the choice of the argument to be in $ (-\pi,\pi )$?

Also I understood that the choice of the branch in which $arg(z) \in (0,2\pi ) $ means excluding the positive part of the real axis.

I do understand that in order to have a continuous function we need to choose specific argument for the complex numbers, but cant see how it is connected to excluding parts of the real axis.

I'd really appreciate an explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the Argand-Gauss plane, the real axis is made up of complex number whose argument is 0 (positive) or \pi (negative)

Comment: you don't have to exclude only parts of real axis. One can actually remove any "nice curve" from the origin to $\infty$, such as a half-line from the origin to $\infty$ (for example, one can remove the ray $\{(r\cos(\pi/4),r\sin(\pi/4))\,:\, r\geq 0\}$ which is at an angle of $\pi/4$). The reason we have to remove something is because otherwise $\frac{dz}{z}$ has no holomorphic primitive (i.e we cannot define a holomorphic branch of $\log$).

Comment: What if I want to exclude the upper part of the imaginary axis. How can I know what would be the range of the arguments?

Comment: sure, you can also remove the upper imaginary axis. In this case, one possible range for the argument is $\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{5\pi}{2}$ (of course we can add overall multiples of $2\pi$, so something like $\frac{9\pi}{2}<\theta<\frac{13\pi}{2}$ is also possible).